# Is the Meteor JS framework compatible with Google App Engine?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, node.js, meteor

Would it be possible to build and deploy `Meteor` applications on Google App Engine or are these incompatible technologies?

I know, for example, that `Node.js` is not compatible with App Engine and Meteor seems similar to Node in some respects.

Comment: It's not a matter of App Engine not supporting node.js so much as it's the fact that App Engine doesn't have a Javascript runtime to run it on.

Comment: Meteor is just a bunch of nicely written JS libraries (their unit tests deserve more attention though). I think you could accomplish something similar using Channels API, but that would probably be a rewrite from scratch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Meteor creates Node.js applications. Google App Engine does not have a JavaScript runtime, but it does have (in beta as of December 2013), [*Managed VMs* which can run Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450321/why-is-javascript-node-js-not-on-google-app-engine/24427331#24427331).

[Google *Compute* Engine (not App Engine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697049/what-is-the-difference-between-google-app-engine-and-google-compute-engine) supports the MEAN stack (Mongo, Express, Angular, Node.js), so you can run Meteor on GCE.

[image: Google App Engine screenshot]

---

*old answer*

Meteor relies on node.js and as such will not run on GAE until GAE supports node.js, if ever.

Comment: This answer does not apply anymore, please update it

Comment: Are you sure? GCE supports it, but not GAE as far as I can tell.

Comment: Not sure because I use heroku. But seems that node.js is compatible with GAE: http://youtu.be/Q8jZHc0NS6A

Answer (score 7):

Meteor runs in Google Compute Engine (GCE), we installed it on a GCE vm using the normal installation procedure and runs quite fine.

Answer (score 3):

A better option would be [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/). They have a Node runtime available, and should give you an experience similar to GAE.

Comment: And it's very easy, I use this buildpack: https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse

Answer (score 3):

Google does support nodejs. So Yes, it is. Start here: https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_nodejs/

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that meteor depends upon node.js. I seem to remember in the intro screencast a mention of being "able to deploy anywhere node.js is available".